# convert byte[] to Object File in Java

Tags: java, file-io, arrays

What is the best way to convert  a byte[] to Object java.io.File? i dont want write this in the disk just get a object File.

Comment: From my client side am sending a file and the server is receiving this like a binary string this binary string , i convert the strig in a byte [], and i need to convert this to File because am using an  API that just accept a file object like parameter. =/, I'm not sure if am doing this right, any suggestions is welcome

Answer (score 2):

The File object is just a wrapper around the name for a real file on the disk. It does not contain any data. You will have to write your byte array into a file first. After the API you then call is done, you can maybe delete that file again. Search for how to manage temporary files in Java.

Answer (score 0):

java has serilazebal interface to persistent  your object;

i guess u want custom serialize method, like c strct;

refences :
https://github.com/MisterChangRay/magic-byte
http://code.google.com/p/javastruct/wiki/HowToUseJavaStruct